# Tamil tag... why?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Continuing my rant on chat, let me rephrase why I don't think is needed, addressing each question problem:

1. **Free tamil word processors**: [Is about a word processor](https://superuser.com/q/14432/235569), not something that critically depends of the language (I'm expecting the installation and functionality goes the same in english, spanish, french, indu and tamil... for something there are icons, no?)
2. **How to change the Linux Localization?**: [any question about locales should have the language you want to change the locale into?](https://superuser.com/q/62031/235569) I say no.
3. **Is it possible to make Notepad++ support Tamil language functionality?**: [same applies for this one](https://superuser.com/q/140655/235569) should we create a tag for each and any weird dialect? I think if it's like that we easily will be using 200 tags just for languages.
4. [**Possiblity to change default language in windows speech recogniton for Tamil**](https://superuser.com/q/458090/235569): wait, what? speech recognition has more to do with that software used that supports the language than the language itself, no? if it's not, I could ask several question about SRS that supports french, english, spanish, german, and create a tag for each of them. I think is fair.

Those four reasons I think that no language tag should be used in any question, except is something really critical that might not work if you don't [take into account the idiom/locales](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90796/regular-expressions-with-grep/90800#comment136638_90800).

So... why is still there? BRING THE BURMINATOR!

Comment: With the first, there's actually unique wordprocessors for tamil - but its a software req, so meh, the question probably ought to be closed anyway

Comment: Well, I actually just see OOo and LO... and said, what the... why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag has been removed from the 4 questions it was placed on. It will automatically be removed from the system in due time.

Comment: Thank you very much *bows*